# Can't replace disjunctive facet with a conjunctive one

Tags: facet, algolia

I'm using the [refinementlist](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#refinementlist) widget. It works perfectly when I use an "or" operator. Although when I change the setting to an "and" operator it throws an error:

> Uncaught Error: my_attribute.name is not a retrieved facet.

The facet is set in the dashboard in Attributes for faceting. (setting as searchable or not searchable doesn't make any difference)
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I had to do is set in my app.js

```
this.helper.state.facets = ['my_attribute.name']
```

And the magic worked. :-)